# toad commit to oracle

Tags: commit, toad

When using Toad for oracle db. Sometimes an issue occurs such that
if you do an insert or an update and use commit button afterwards, it actually
does not commit until closing the toad application. But it seems that toad committed it
but the application can not see the commitment until toad is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my TOAD for SQL Server (ver 6.1).

I suggest you change the database properties themselves to AUTO commit from SSMS directly. TOAD is not the problem, it's your database settings.